# Looking for trustworthy JPEG batch converter/resizer

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

I have a batch of PNG files that I need to convert to JPEG. I'm looking for a free trustworthy utility that will give me the most optimal possible JPEGs.

I've found some paid utilities and i HAVE Photoshop, but I want something dedicated that is made for the task and I dont want to accidentally download spy ware.

I'm really surprised not to find this question already on StackOverflow, but please point me in the direction of any similar questions if they exist.

Comment: it's not on SO because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Yes it is. This sort of thing can be quite important in web programming, particularly with migrations.

Comment: i almost mentioned that but decided to just leave at least a hint that that may be the case. at the end of the day it ISNT a programming question, but very useful to many many programmers - especially if theyve been provided with images and they dont have photoshop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One word: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Not sure about if it generates the absolute smallest JPEGs you can get, but it's certainly good and would be my first choice.

Answer (score 3):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is another option.  It has a "Batch Convert/Rename" feature, but it's a Windows-only GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can do batch conversion of images.

mogrify -format jpg *.png  <= Converts all png files to jpg

Answer (score 0):

The ImageMagick [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) utility should do everything you require. There are [a number of options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write) which you can use to control the JPEG output quality.